# Find X in the Equation

Tags: modular-arithmetic, linear-transformations, education, prime-factorization

I'm not a mathematician and I have forgotten about some basics in mathematics. 
I have this equation:

$$x^y \pmod z = w$$

Given $y, z,$ and $w,$ how will I find $x$? How will I get the equation for $x$?

Comment: (old joke): I found $x$, it is inside the parentheses: $$(\boxed{x}^y) \mod z = w$$

Comment: @Michael Lol.Anyways how will I get the equation for x?

Comment: Please refer to [how to ask a good question](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) to help you improve formatting and your tags

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume here that $x,y,z,w$ are integers (and $y$ is a positive integer).  Then your equation means: 
$$ x^y = rz+w$$
for some integer $r$.  Now note that if $x$ has this property, then so does $x+kz$ for any integer $k$.  So it suffices to search for $x \in \{0, 1, 2, ..., z-1\}$.

Example: 
$$x^{11} \mod 5 = 2 $$

Try $x \in \{0, 1, 2, 3, 4\}$: 
\begin{align}
0^{11} = 0 \: (mod 5)\\
1^{11} = 1 \: (mod 5) \\
2^{11} = 3 \: (mod 5) \\
\boxed{3^{11} = 2} \: (mod 5) \\
4^{11} = 4 \: (mod 5)
\end{align}
So then solutions are $x=3+5k$ for all integers $k$.

---

The $\mod z$ operation is equal to the remainder when we divide by $z$. So for example

- $Rem[26/5] = 1$ if and only if $26-1$ is divisible by $5$.
- $Rem[83/9] = 2$ if and only if $83-2$ is divisible by $9$.
- $Rem[26/7] = 5$ if and only if $26 - 5$ is divisible by $7$.
- $Rem[n/z] = w$ if and only if $n-w$ is divisible by $z$.

In particular $Rem[n/z]=w$ if and only if $n-w= rz$ for some integer $r$.

If we take $n=x^y$ then we see that $Rem[x^y/z]=w$ if and only if $x^y - w = rz$ for some integer $r$.

Comment: Thank you so much but how did u get the rz term. Or what is the opposite operation of a modulo? Can you explain it step by step. Thank you again.

Comment: See my added content on this.